# When TableView reloadData, the cpu usage rise violently

Tags: ios, uitableview, cpu, cpu-usage, reloaddata

I have a complex `tableView`, which's cell have many contents.

> [image]

And when I `reloadData` my `tableView`, the cpu usage raise up quickly, even to 180%!

[image]

So, in real device, `5c` or `5s`, the app will crash, I think is because the cpu usage the app crash.

So, is there a method to limit the cpu usage or let app do not crash?

---

**Addition-1**

I don't think the `tableView delegate methods` is help for the question ,but I will also put part of them:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:exp_TableIdentifier]; 

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LMLAgricultureTechCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:exp_TableIdentifier];
    }

    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).model = self.help_dataSource[indexPath.row];
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).indexPath = indexPath;
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).delegate = self;
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).photo_view.delegate = self;

    // solve SDWebImage memory increase
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache clearMemory];

    return cell;
}
```

In the `LMLAgricultureTechCell.m`:

```
- (void)setModel:(LMLAgricultureTechModel *)model{

_model = model;

_shouldOpenContentLabel = NO;

// 1.头像
_iconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:model.lml_iconName];
[_iconView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.lml_iconName] placeholderImage:img_placeholder_circle_header];
[Util roundBorderView:_iconView.bounds.size.width / 2.0 border:0 color:nil view:_iconView];
// 2.名字
_nameLabel.text = model.lml_userName == nil || [model.lml_userName  isEqual: @""] || [model.lml_userName isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? @"" : model.lml_userName;  // 未获得用户名
// 防止单行文本Label在重新用的时候宽度计算不准的问题
[_nameLabel sizeToFit];
// 3.地址
_loacation.text = model.lml_location == nil || [model.lml_location  isEqual: @""] || [model.lml_location isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? @"" : [model.lml_location componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"].lastObject;  //未获得地址

// 4.时间
_time.text = model.lml_time == nil  || [model.lml_time  isEqual: @""] || [model.lml_time isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? @"" : model.lml_time;
```

// 未获取时间
    [_time sizeToFit];

```
// 5.标题
_title.text = model.lml_title == nil  || [model.lml_title  isEqual: @""] || [model.lml_title isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? @"" : model.lml_title;  //未获得标题

//[_title sizeToFit];

// 6.内容
_content.text = model.lml_content;
_photo_view.picPathStringsArray = model.lml_imagesArr;


// 7.如果文字高度超过60
if (model.shouldShowMoreButton) {
    _allContent.sd_layout.heightIs(20);
    _allContent.hidden = NO;
    // 如果需要展开
    if (model.isOpening) {
        _content.sd_layout.maxHeightIs(MAXFLOAT);
        [_allContent setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"收起", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        _content.sd_layout.maxHeightIs(maxContentLabelHeight);
        [_allContent setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"全文", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}else {

    _allContent.sd_layout.heightIs(0);
    _allContent.hidden = YES;
}


if (model.isMyPost) {

    _delete.sd_layout.heightIs(20).widthIs(40);
    _delete.hidden = NO;
}else {

    _delete.sd_layout.heightIs(0);
    _delete.hidden = YES;
}

// 8.现在判断allOrDelete back
if (_allContent.hidden == YES && _delete.hidden == YES) {
    _allAndDeleteView.sd_layout.heightIs(0);
}else {

    _allAndDeleteView.sd_layout.heightIs(20);
}

// 9.图片数组
CGFloat picContainerTopMargin = 0;
if (model.lml_imagesArr.count) {
    picContainerTopMargin = 10;
}
_photo_view.sd_layout.topSpaceToView(_allAndDeleteView, picContainerTopMargin);
_photo_view.picPathStringsArray = model.lml_imagesArr;

_showCountlabel.text = model.lml_scanTimes;
_goodImageView.image = model.lml_isLiked ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"pre_list_thumb_selected.png"]:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pre_list_thumb"];
_goodCountlabel.text = model.lml_likeTimes;
_speakCountlabel.text = model.lml_commentTimes;

  // 底部的
_bottomView = part3;

[self setupAutoHeightWithBottomView:_bottomView bottomMargin:15];

}
```

Comment: Are you downloading image by using `[NSURL URLWithString:model.lml_iconName]` in tableviewcell every time the cell loads?

Comment: Simulator run time does not necessarily equate to device run time.  1) its simulated on an entirely different architecture (x64 vs ARM) 2) there is all kinds of debug code running between Xcode and the simulator.  Run on device and see if you have a problem.  If you do then use instruments to profile and figure out where that problem actually is.  Its pointless to optimize based on debug run time in a simulated environment.

Comment: @Josh Homann, But in my real device it will crash, and the cpu usage is also high.

Comment: @KrishnaCA Hi,bro. I use `SDWebImage`, you see this line:`[_iconView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.lml_iconName] placeholderImage:img_placeholder_circle_header];`